# How to get sum of observations of a variable using sapply/lapply for a list of data frames?

Tags: r, list, lapply, sapply

I want to get the sum of values for a variable in each data frame in a list. I have something similar to this:

```
l <- list(a = mtcars, b = mtcars, c = mtcars)  
v <- sapply(l, function(x)sum(l$x$disp))
```

I expect to get a named vector containing sums. Instead I get only zeros. My guess would be that only name of the data frame is passed to the function.

I tried other functions and lapply but every time I get a list/vector with Nulls or zeros. It is possible to use for statement for this task, but in my case I have list containing lists of data frames and nested loops in R seem not to be a good choice.
Do you have any ideas what I am missing? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are calling 'list' instead of 'l' in sapply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need,

```
sapply(l, function(x) sum(x["disp"]))

#  a      b      c 
#7383.1 7383.1 7383.1
```

Or if you need the complete sum of `disp` variable across all the list, you can wrap it completely in `sum`

```
sum(sapply(l, function(x) sum(x["disp"])))

#[1] 22149.3
```